# How can I handle System.StackOverflowException?

Tags: random, stack, c++-cli, overflow, system

This error appears sometimes only when I call a recursive function of which one of the parameters is a number: `rand()%10`. Just like in the code down below:

```
private: System::Void AIrandomMove(int randomMove,String ^s)
{
if (randomMove == 1)
{
    if ( Move(1) ) // move number 1 had already been done
        AIrandomMove(rand()%10,s);  // here it appears the    System.StackOverflowException
    else
         //do move number 1
}
//same goes for ==2 || ==3 || ... || ==10
}
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: Just don't rely on recursive code with a recursive case choice given by a random number extraction as it makes no sense. Convert the algorithm to an iterative one.

Comment: Why it makes no sense? The implementation is something like this:
`    if(randomMove == 4)
    {
        if ( that move have been made before)
            AIrandomMove(rand%10,s);
        else
            //implementation
    }`

Comment: it makes no sense because you are explicitly allowing non-termination behavior. What's the point of using recursion? I mean why do you require recursion?

Comment: @RazvanNica Please [edit] your post to include all of the relevant details, and avoid putting those details in the comments.

Comment: Well, if this is a non-termination behavior, what are the odds to often run as it should? Only sometimes the Stack Overflow appears.

Comment: That's because the termination of the recursive algorithm depends on a random value extraction, as pointed out in my first comment, so you basically have some code which might or might not terminate according to how much you are lucky, which isn't a proper design.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius  I edited it =)

Comment: @Jack So, your suggestion is to convert the algorithm to an iterative one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper recursive algorithm works under two assumptions:

- you have a base case which terminate the recursion (so the function doesn't call itself)
- you have a recursive case which invokes the function itself with different arguments so that there is some progression involved

This translates in something like:

```
void recursive(inArgs) {
  if (condition)
    return;
  else
    recursive(outArgs)
}
```

It's clear that if `condition` is the expression `true` then this code never terminates (hence it will eventually raise a stack overflow).

In your situation `condition` is evaluated through a random value comparison. Now, assume condition is `rand()%2 == 0`. So basically each time it is evaluated you have `50%` chance of being `true` and `50%` of being `false`.

This doesn't guarantee that the recursion will terminate, as a path with n `true` evaluation exists (and it probability can be calculated). That's the problem with your design.

If many moves have been already made (or maybe all of them) then recursion won't end.

You don't need recursion at all in your case, since you could store the available moves in a set and remove them once they are not available anymore (possibly shuffling the set to then choose one randomly). Or even a simpler solution would be something like:

```
int choosenMove = rand()%10;

while (Move(choosenMove)) {
  choosenMove = rand()%10;
  // do move choosenMove
}
```

But this doesn't guarantee termination neither if you don't make sure that a state in which no moves are available can't happen.

Comment: Oh.. Ok. Now I finally get it. Thanks a lot. 
It's 3 AM in my country and I definitely need some rest. Nevertheless, I got it!
Thanks again! =)